# Не работает код. JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Недавно начал изучать js (1month), и нашел готовый код для плавной прокрутки к якорю, но к сожалению js and jQuery слегка ругаются. Попытался разобраться сам (потратил час, как минимум)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#navigation").on("click","a", function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       let id  = $(this).attr('href'),
           top = $(id).offset().top;
       $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1500);
   });
});
```

```
<ul class="flex items-center ml-auto mr-auto" id="navigation">
    <li class="underline-one ml-10"><a href="#sposob">Способ применения</a></li>
    <li class="underline-one mx-10"><a href="#Adress">Адрес</a></li>
    <div class="mr-5">
        <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="" class="w-24">
    </div>
    <li class="underline-one mx-10"><a href="#contact">Контакты</a></li>
    <li class="underline-one mx-10"><a href="#catalog">Каталог</a></li>
</ul>
```

сама ошибка в консоли браузера -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.js:5:33)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5:14113)
    at HTMLUListElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:5:10850)
(anonymous) @ index.js:5
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:5
v.handle @ jquery.min.js:5
index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.js:5:33)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:5:14113)
```

ошибка в соурсе - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'top')`

использую фреймворк tailwind.

Comment: "слегка ругаются" --- не очень-то детальное пояснение проблемы, вам не кажется?

Comment: прошу прощения, забыл с консоли добавить, пока регистрировался, запамятовал совсем. Исправил

Comment: вот это: `let id  = $(this).attr('href'),
           top = $(id).offset().top;`  --- очень странная запись. в href не может быть id. и как следствие `.top` говорит что не может быть такого свойства, потому что в `$(id)` явно будет не поиск по селектору и идентификатору.... и кстати, надо будет наверняка писать что-то типа `$('#' + id)`.....  отладка поможет в этом деле

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, _в href не может быть id_ - ну вообще может, и очень часто бывает, для работы с якорями, что собственно тут и происходит

Comment: Проверь наличие элементов с указанными `id` на странице. Очевидно, какого-то из них, или нескольких нет на странице, поэтому `$(id)` возвращает пустую коллекцию, и `offset` у пустой коллекции возвращает `undefined`

Comment: @Grundy. Использую id "navigation" лишь только в блоке обертке в примере

Comment: проблема не с `id "navigation"`, а с элементами, к которым должна осуществляться прокрутка: `#sposob`,  `#Adress` и другие

Comment: До добавления js/jquery якори работали исправно, (извините если не так понимаю, только начинаю)

Comment: @Daniil, необходимо просто проверить наличие этих элементов. Кроме тебя это никто не может сделать.